# Accessing this.props function in react ComponentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access parent function (passed as property to child) in child's componentDidMount() but it is showing as undefined.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.actionis = this.props.actionis.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.actionis(selectednow, 'disabled');
}
```

**EDIT:** 
Parent Constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        var abc = "";
        this.handlerHeading = this.handlerHeading.bind(this)
        this.handlerHeadingRemove = this.handlerHeadingRemove.bind(this)
     }
```

Parent Render():

```
<Mappingcomp actionis={this.handlerHeading} />
```

handlerHeading Function:

```
handlerHeading(index, disabled) {
        xarraydis.push(index);
    }
```

Error Is:

> this.actionis is not a function

But i can access it in `render()` function and not in `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: How are you passing the function down to the child, Can you add that part. Also do the binding in the parent and not in the child, you can directly call the function from props rather than assigning that to a class variable in child

Comment: please check edit

Comment: You don't need to `bind()` it! Just call `this.props.actionis(selectednow, 'disabled')`. You only need to `bind` the function inside of your Parent component (which you probably have done).

Comment: @Dan it do not work that way either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to bind a `prop` callback function.

Just do

```
componentDidMount(){
    // don't forget to define selectednow
    this.props.actionis(selectednow, 'disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to bind the returned arguments in the parent with the function like

```
<Mappingcomp actionis={(index, disabled) => this.handlerHeading(index, disabled)} />
```

and then in the child use

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.props.actionis(selectednow, 'disabled');
}
```